# IFERROR, Index Match formula with too many arguements

Tags: excel, indexing

I am trying to lookup data in a 26 page spreedsheet based off a client number. Each sheet is labeled as a letter to organise for surnames. Each sheet has the following table:

```
Surname | Forename | Client Number | Daily Ticket Count | Monthly Ticket Count |
Ticket No | Date | Ticket No2 | Date | Ticket No3 | Date | Ticket No4 | Date | 
Ticket No 5 | Date
```

I'm searching by client Number to pull all assigned tickets. This formula below is to only check Ticket No, and then there is another formula in another cell to search Ticket No2. Repeat for Tickets 3 to 5.

This is my current formula. I was planning on repeating this entirely for each sheet A-Z, but that isn't feasible apparently. Is it possible to still do this by using another function, and if so what function?

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A!F2:F36,(MATCH($B12,A!C2:C36,0))),INDEX(B!F2:F36,(MATCH($B12,B!C2:C36,0))),
 INDEX(C!F2:F36,(MATCH($B12,C!C2:C36,0))))
```

Comment: Morning. Can you paste the full array that is the result of highlighting this portion only: INDIRECT("'"&INDEX(Sheets,MATCH(TRUE,Arry1>=ROWS($‌​1:1),0))&"'!C3:C100")="TEST" in the formula bar and pressing F9? It should be an array consisting of 98 Boolean TRUE/FALSE returns. Might be even better in terms of space-saving/legibility if you do a Find and Replace on the resulting string to replace all TRUEs with T and FALSEs with F.

Comment: I actually set up the mass IFERROR spam formula posted earlier, tweaked to use Index Match this morning. I was given a deadline this morning so don't have the time to keep fiddling to get this working I'm afraid. Again, thanks for the time you spent, I do appreciate it.

Comment: Ok. You're welcome, and sorry I couldn't get it to work for you in time.

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with

```
=IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(VLOOKUP($B12,A!C:F,4,FALSE),VLOOKUP($B12,B!C:F,4,FALSE)),VLOOKUP($B12,C!C:F,4,FALSE)),VLOOKUP($B12,D!C:F,4,FALSE)),VLOOKUP($B12,E!C:F,4,FALSE)),VLOOKUP($B12,F!C:F,4,FALSE)),VLOOKUP($B12,G!C:F,4,FALSE)),VLOOKUP($B12,H!C:F,4,FALSE)),VLOOKUP($B12,I!C:F,4,FALSE)),VLOOKUP($B12,J!C:F,4,FALSE)),VLOOKUP($B12,K!C:F,4,FALSE)),VLOOKUP($B12,L!C:F,4,FALSE)),VLOOKUP($B12,M!C:F,4,FALSE)),VLOOKUP($B12,N!C:F,4,FALSE)),VLOOKUP($B12,O!C:F,4,FALSE)),VLOOKUP($B12,P!C:F,4,FALSE)),VLOOKUP($B12,Q!C:F,4,FALSE)),VLOOKUP($B12,R!C:F,4,FALSE)),VLOOKUP($B12,S!C:F,4,FALSE)),VLOOKUP($B12,T!C:F,4,FALSE)),VLOOKUP($B12,U!C:F,4,FALSE)),VLOOKUP($B12,V!C:F,4,FALSE)),VLOOKUP($B12,W!C:F,4,FALSE)),VLOOKUP($B12,X!C:F,4,FALSE)),VLOOKUP($B12,Y!C:F,4,FALSE)),VLOOKUP($B12,Z!C:F,4,FALSE))
```

?

Comment: And if there were 100 sheets, you'd simply add another 74 IFERROR clauses?

Comment: I wouldn't but OP is more lazy than me.

Comment: Wouldn't say lazy, but definitely fed up of this damn spreadsheet. That said, this works, I just have to go through and change to get the other 4 ticket numbers in separate cells. Cheers.

Comment: Made a VBA to show off, @XOR LX feel free to use it.

Comment: My business is to provide alternatives to VBA, where possible! Cheers, anyway!

Comment: Will the mass of IFERROR work if I did each one for a Index Match function after? 
`IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR((INDEX(A!F2:F36,(MATCH($B12,A!C2:C36,0))),INDEX(B!F2:F36,(MATCH($B12,B!C2:C36,0))),
 INDEX(C!F2:F36,(MATCH($B12,C!C2:C36,0))))`

Comment: Yes it will, but the charactercount might limit your opportunities. If you look up the values in `C` and grab values from `F` then `VLOOKUP` is more convenient.

Comment: I'll have to do it eventually as I'll be looking up values in C, and grab from A & B at a later date as well, which is why I'm trying to get XOR LX's formulas working. Thanks for your help though.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a VBA solution for the same task, for you it's `=ertdfgcvb($B12,C1;F1;Arry1)` where `Arry1` is a range that contains the sheet names, in your preference order.

```
Public Function ertdfgcvb(Lookup_val As Variant, Lookup_col As Range, Grab_col As Range, ShtArr As Range)
Dim ws As Worksheet, rng As Range

Find1 = Lookup_col.Column
Grab1 = Grab_col.Column

On Error Resume Next
For Each rng In ShtArr
    Set ws = Sheets(rng.Value2)
    ertdfgcvb = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Lookup_val, ws.Columns(Find1), ws.Columns(Grab1))
    Exit Function
Next
End Function
```